# ¿Cómo se entiende las frases que terminan en "as phuck"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

He estado viendo camisetas con frases como:

> Married *as phuck*
>
> Boricua *as phuck*
>
> Gay *as phuck*

¿Me pueden ayudar a entender estas frases, ya que no he encontrado una traducción aceptable al español?

Saludos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [SL](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/)! Por favor, ten en cuenta que en este sitio nos especializamos en preguntas acerca del idioma español. Tu pregunta tiene más bien que ver con el idioma inglés, del cual podemos saber más o menos, pero lo mejor es que un nativo te defina el término haciendo esta pregunta en [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/) y así seguramente podrás encontrar una traducción adecuada al español.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to http://english.stackexchange.com/ and is also asking for transaltions that is again off-topic,

Comment: De hecho, ahora que me estoy dando cuenta, hay dos sitios diferenciados para el idioma inglés. _[English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)_, que es para expertos en la materia, y _[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)_, que es para gente que está aprendiendo inglés como segunda lengua. Esta pregunta sería perfecta para este segundo sitio.

Comment: Bienvenido, y recuerda que, si alguna respuesta te satisface, puedes aceptarla pinchando en la marca de correcto que hay debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta (ese número en la posición superior izquierda de ella). Al hacerlo, la marca cambiará a verde.

Answer (score 6):

El mejor sitio para encontrar significados del inglés slang es [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/).

Lo primero sería buscar ***[phuck](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=phuck)***, que parece que es un término usado para decir *fuck* pero en contextos tecnológicos. Según los ejemplos no parece que sea el caso, así que supongo que simplemente será una forma de decir *fuck* pero sin escribirla tal cual (algo similar a como cuando alguien escribe *conio* por no escribir la palabra real).

Lo siguiente ya es buscar la expresión ***[as fuck](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=as%20fuck)***, que parece que es una expresión usada para enfatizar cualquier adjetivo. Así que simplemente tenemos que buscar una forma de enfatizar en español que suene malsonante. Por probar:

> Casado y con un par (de huevos)
>
> [Boricua](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boricua) de cojones
>
> Gay de la hostia

Estas expresiones enfáticas pueden variar según la zona, yo he usado algunas del español de España. ¿Alguna otra alternativa por parte de los usuarios de América Latina?

Comment: Otra usada en España: "del copón (bendito)". También se puede insertar un "mil pares de" entre _de_ y _cojones_. Otras versiones menos malsonantes (y menos enfáticas) serían "de órdago" o "del quince".